# How to denormalize the data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, denormalization

My view data looks like this :

## Data:

```
Country  qty   Amt    type
India     42   1000   1
India     32    59    2
```

I'm trying to denormalize the view data based on country, so that, two rows should be appeared as one row.

## Required Form :

```
 Country  qty   Amt    type  qty    Amt    type
 India     42   1000   1      32    59     2
```

As I'm a newbie to MySQL, Can anyone please help me out regarding the same...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to denormalize a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890/what-is-a-good-way-to-denormalize-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a `join`:

```
select t1.country, t1.qty, t1.amt, t1.type, t2.qty, t2.amt, t2.type
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.country = t2.country and t1.type = 1 and t2.type = 2;
```

Comment: I had edited my question. Can I denormalize the data while creating a view itself ?

Comment: @dev007 - Since you're grouping by Type, and it's unknown how many types there may be for any given country, this would amount to creating an unknown number of columns in the view.  This is not possible to express with SQL.

Comment: There are three types in the dataset. It won't exceed 3.

Comment: Then you can't do a group by.  You need to join in each type explicitly, as described above.

Comment: @Gordon, the join query which you have mentioned worked out. Thanks a lot for your help. But, Is there any possibility to build a denormalization query while creating a view itself ?

Comment: @dev007 You might be looking for a "pivot"..  Not sure how to do them with mySQL though..

Comment: @dev007 . . . I don't fully understand your comment.  You should ask another question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is not just one two row you want to merge to one , rather n number of row if have are of india they should be one row . If that is the case , you can use simply Self join .

```
select * from t as t1,t as t2 where t1.country = t2.country
```